# Batch file to move photos of specific resolution only

Tags: windows-8, batch-file, photo, resolution

I have a folder with several thousands of photos with varying resolutions. I now need to categorize them all by resolution (dimensions). I can try doing that manually in Windows 8 by searching for something like:

```
*.jpg height: > 1200 width: > 2000
```

and then move the results to subfolder.

But there should be a way of doing that with a batch file. Any idea how would it look like?

Answer (score 1):

The free image viewer `Ifanview` also has a command line and is able to provide a list of files and resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with pure batch.Should consider using an external command line tool.I would recommend imagemagick (totally irreplaceable tool when dealing with images from command line ):
http://www.imagemagick.org/

here how you can get image dimensions:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php